# Scrolling Music Notes and Lyrics

Tags: javascript, text, scroll

I am attempting to create scrolling text that represent the lyrics of a song.  As the text scrolls to the left (and as the song progresses), I would like to represent guitar chords (music notes) above the scrolling text whenever appropriate.  Would this be even possible?

How would I catch when to display the notes as the text scrolls?  Would javascript or a js library (jquery) be the best way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to make use of a jquery slideshow utility, 
but you could accomplish it very easy with a bunch of HTML elements where based on a periodic timer (setInterval) in javascript you decrement their X position, hiding the ones that go below your left edge threshhold and displaying the ones that drop below your right threshhold,.